# Is it possible to derive pmf from a CDF with no support given?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function, geometric-distribution

Given a CDF of random variable, $$F_X(x)=\sum_{j=1}^x \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^j = 1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x$$,
I want to derive pmf of this random variable $X$. But there is no information about support of this random variable, so I think that to derive pmf, I have to calculate $F(x)-F(x-)$.
But how can I do this? If I consider the support of x to be 'nearly' continuous, an action similar to differentiation will yield $\frac{d}{dx} \left\{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x\right\} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x \ln{2}$.
However, I'm not sure if this is mathematically correct. How is it right to derive the pmf with only the above information? Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: For a discrete r.v. $f(x_i)=F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1})$, for all i.

Comment: The support is implicitly made of positive integers since $F_X(x)$ is using a summation from $1$ to $x$. This is the geometric distribution.